# How to combine several SQL queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine the results of several queries into one but I wonder if it's even possible.
First query counts number of games every refery has in given year:

```
SELECT  count(1),ejl_refery.surname FROM  ejl_protocols 
left join ejl_refery on ejl_protocols.refery = ejl_refery.id
WHERE  ejl_protocols.season = 2013 group by refery
```

Second query counts number of penalties each refery assigned:

```
SELECT  count(1),ejl_refery.surname FROM  ejl_protocols 
left join ejl_play_events on ejl_protocols.id = ejl_play_events.protocol_id
left join ejl_refery on ejl_protocols.refery = ejl_refery.id
WHERE  ejl_protocols.season = 2013 and ejl_play_events.event_id  in (3,4) 
group by refery
```

And I have 1 more similar query.
The result should be a SQL that would enalbe to generate table like:

```
Refery Surname | Number of games | Number of penalties | Number of cards |
```

I tried some combinations to put it together, but they all ended in syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to treat each query as a derived table, and join them together.  The only thing you have in your queries to join on would be surname, but since that's all your grouping on that shouldn't matter.

```
Select
g.surname,
g,games,
p.penalties

from
(SELECT  count(1) as games,ejl_refery.surname FROM  ejl_protocols 
left join ejl_refery on ejl_protocols.refery = ejl_refery.id
WHERE  ejl_protocols.season = 2013 group by refery) g
inner join 
(SELECT  count(1) as penalties,ejl_refery.surname FROM  ejl_protocols 
left join ejl_play_events on ejl_protocols.id = ejl_play_events.protocol_id
left join ejl_refery on ejl_protocols.refery = ejl_refery.id
WHERE  ejl_protocols.season = 2013 and ejl_play_events.event_id  in (3,4) 
group by refery) p
on g.surname = p.surname
```

If you have a third query, you can just add it in there using the same logic.

Comment: I get syntax error: Unknown column 'g.surname' in 'field list'. Edit: Stupid me - there was typo in SQL G-><-g